# How to get value from JSON "object in object" using GSON in Android

Tags: android, json, gson

My JSON response looks like

```
[{"order":-1,"artist":[{"name":"Hey"}]},...]
```

How I can get `name` from `artist` object using GSON?

---

I tried to use something like this

```
private String getArtistName(){
    ...
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Order>>() {}.getType();
    List<Order> details = gson.fromJson(MyJSONresponse, type);
    for (Order order : details) {
        if (order.order == -1) {
            String artistName = // I don't know what to enter here
            return artistName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private class Order{
   int order;
   List<Artist> artist = new ArrayList<Artist>();
}

pricate class Artist{
   String name;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
    int order;
    List<Artist> artist;
}

class Artist {
    String name;
}

MyClass myClass = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonString, MyClass[].class);
myClass.artist.get(0).name;
```

Comment: Error `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 23` :(

Comment: there you go, it should be something like this.